# Gitlab not create issue from email

Tags: gitlab

I use gitlab version 16.6.1 created and connected mailbox servicedeskGitLab@domain.com

gitlab-rake gitlab:incoming_email:check`

Checking Incoming Email …
Incoming Email: … Checking Reply by email …

IMAP server credentials are correct? … Checking servicedeskGitLab@domain.com
yes

Mailroom enabled? … skipped
MailRoom running? … skipped
Checking Reply by email … Finished
Checking Incoming Email … Finished

if an external user sends email to servicedeskGitLab+user-userprojectname-7-issue-@domain.com, it arrives in the mailbox servicedeskGitLab@domain.com but the issue is not created. In this case, letters arrive in the mailbox and are even marked as read.

gitlab.rb:

```
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_address'] = "smtp.domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_port'] = 465
gitlab_rails['smtp_user_name'] = "servicedeskGitLab@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_password'] =
gitlab_rails['smtp_domain'] = "domain.com"
gitlab_rails['smtp_authentication'] = "login"
gitlab_rails['smtp_enable_starttls_auto'] = false
gitlab_rails['smtp_tls'] = true
gitlab_rails['smtp_openssl_verify_mode'] = 'peer'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_from'] = 'servicedeskGitLab@domain.com'
gitlab_rails['gitlab_email_reply_to'] = 'servicedeskGitLab@domain.com'

gitlab_rails['incoming_email_enabled'] = true
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_address'] = "servicedeskGitLab+%{key}@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_email'] = "servicedeskGitLab@domain.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_password'] =
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_host'] = "smtp.domain.com"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_port'] = 993
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_ssl'] = true
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_start_tls'] = false
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_mailbox_name'] = "inbox"
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_idle_timeout'] = 60
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_delete_after_delivery'] = true
gitlab_rails['incoming_email_expunge_deleted'] = true
```

I will be very grateful for tips.